# unstable wifi conection Ubuntu 14.04 Acer Aspire V 13

Tags: wireless, drivers, acer, connection, atheros

I have problems to connect via Wifi with my Acer Aspire V 13 V3-371-39MA for several month. The strange thing is, sometimes I can connect and the conection would stay for the whole day...on other days it's not possible at all or isn't working for few hours and suddenly I can connect. In the beginning this problem wasn't so bad and mostly everthing worked out fine, but now I have this problem whereever I try to connect and I tried it with several routers already.
With a wired connection the internet works out very well.

I was already making some research and from what I red I assume that it has to do with the wifi driver. I found out that my network adaptor is an Atheros 9462.

That article might be similar to my problem, but none of the commands really worked out ( it could have been my fault, as I'm not that much into ubuntu at the moment):
[Atheros AR9462 WiFI very unstable & package loss](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301442/atheros-ar9462-wifi-very-unstable-package-loss)

Is there anybody who is able to explain me in simple words how I could solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this on my computer, I dont know why this happens but the solution that worked for me was to disconnect from your internet and reconnect and re-enter that code to access your internet.

Comment: THanks, but I tried that already. That's not helping it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of two things:

1.
Your computer's network adaptor is the issue, this means that you computer keeps disconnecting from the network. This can be solved by contacting the company you got the computer from.

Or 2.

You router is loosing connection to the internet, this means that all the devices loose connection to the internet but stay connected to the router. This means that you should contact your internet service provider. This happened to me, the technical support rep changed some settings on their end and now everything is working fine!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm pretty sure that its not the router, as it's also not working in university and they sould have a stable conection. But if you think it's the networks adapter then, you suppose it's a hardware problem? Not something related to the driver?