# Problems with WiFi AR9462

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have a problem with wifi on my new notebook: acer vn7-571 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. If I stay nearby the accesspoint it works fine, but if I leave the room (more than 3-4 meters to accesspoint) the connection get lost after a few minutes. In this case I can not use firefox and I also get no answer for ping www.google.de, etc.

I already compiled backports as discribed here by myself (without errors) but it didn't helped me either. I also tried `ath9k.conf` settings described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178054), also without success (by the way after installation I did not found the file `/etc/modeprobe.d/ath9k.conf` so I created it by myself: maybe it can not work that way?).

I hope, someone have another hints for me: thanks!

my network chip:

```
    sudo lshw -c Network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: 20:6a:8a:99:c4:55
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:61 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b3600000-b3600fff memory:b3400000-b3403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 30:10:b3:77:d5:d7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.178.37 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:b3500000-b357ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb0ffff
```

Now I tried almost all of suggestions from here: [Atheros AR9462 WiFI very unstable & package loss](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301442/atheros-ar9462-wifi-very-unstable-package-loss)

But it also did not helped me at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/301442/atheros-ar9462-wifi-very-unstable-package-loss