# Wifi Adapter missing on 19.04

Tags: wireless, asus, 19.04, adapter

Wifi adapter is sometimes showing up and most of the time missing. I'm on 19.04. My laptop is Asus K401U.

When I run this: sudo lshw -c network, I only get the Ethernet interface and no Wireless interface.

When the wifi showed up the other day, I tried running: sudo lshw -c network
and I got this information:

```
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atheros AR9462 WiFI very unstable & package loss](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301442/atheros-ar9462-wifi-very-unstable-package-loss)